# So weird error from Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
if($("#target").html().trim().length>0){do sth}
```

it is weird i got the error says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
and in the html i have

```
<div id="target"><table><tr><td>ABC</td></tr></table></div>
```

And the weird issue is if i do the `console.info($("#target").html().trim().length)`, it will tell me some number.

and the most weird thing i found the only way to avoid that error is change the html content

```
<div id="target">ABC</div>
```

without the html table, it will do not throw that errow

Comment: did you remember to put your code in a `$(document).ready()` handler?

Comment: since when is "trim()" a valid string-overloaded function? maybe it's new, but i *only* know to use "jQuery.trim(STRING);" and so -- check the OUTPUT of "trim()" at the end of chain with "console.log" please

Comment: yes, i put them in ready

Comment: string.trim() is perfectly fine, so is someString.trim().length

Comment: `.trim()` isn't necessary here. Also, I just tested this and echoed 51 with `$("#target").html().length` and also your original code (in Chrome)

Comment: @Endy but not on all browsers...

Comment: and i thing it is not issue with trim(), actually when i remove the trim(), it also give error, so that should me the html() problem

Comment: me too, if using console.info it can give me some number, so i say it is weird

Comment: the odd thing is that it's not supposed to be possible to get an `undefined` result from `String.trim()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use innerHTML or innerText directly instead of Jquery

Answer (score 4):

change your `$("#target").html().trim().length`

to

```
$("#target").text().trim().length
```

check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMNGQ/2/), you are getting length as 51, because it is giving the length of html between ***`<div>`*** tag

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements.

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched
>   elements

Comment: it works, but sometimes i just want to figure out the html rather than the text

Comment: @john, you can try `InnerHtml` length for the html length.

Comment: @Furqan but the question was tagged jquery :-)

Comment: @Sibu, jquery is a wrapper of javascript as far as I know, and does not prohibit using intermixed javascript.